# How to get number of occurrences in an array in array? Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays

In JavaScript, I want to count the number of times "N" in is in the first, second, third, fourth column. I want each other there values. I want to get the number of occurrences in an array in array, and then get four numbers equal the occurrences.

input:

```
var set =[
['N', 'N', 'Y', 'N'],
['1', 'N', '2', 'N'],
['N', '1', '4', 'N'],
['2', 'N', 'N', '1']]
```

output: 3 2 2 2

Comment: To get the output of `3 2 2 2`, one needs to count the number of `N` per-row. Say the input is in an array named `inpArr`, please try something like this: `console.log(inpArr.map(arr => arr.filter(x => x === 'N').length));`

Comment: If you need to count the `N`s in each column, that requires a different approach. Plus, it will get you a result of: `2 3 1 3` (for the input-array provided in the question, above).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
const set = [
  ['N', 'N', 'Y', 'N'],
  ['1', 'N', '2', 'N'],
  ['N', '1', '4', 'N'],
  ['2', 'N', 'N', '1'],
];
const countNs = row => row.reduce((acc, curr) => acc + (curr === 'N' ? 1 : 0), 0);
// number of Ns in each row
console.log(set.map(countNs));
const transpose = a => a[0].map((_, c) => a.map(r => r[c]));
// Number of Ns in each column
console.log(transpose(set).map(countNs));
```

Comment: Please consider if `countNs` may be simplified like so: `const countNs = row => (row.filter(x => x === 'N') || []).length;`

Comment: I'm fairly new to JS so could you please explain(I want to learn)..... `row.reduce(acc,curr) ` I understand the curr is the current value but what is the acc variable?  Also in `a[0].map((_,c))` - what are the variables being passed (underscore and c)?

Comment: @jsN00b There is no reason for `|| []` in your simplification. [`filter()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) always returns a result. If nothing matches an empty array is returned. So `const countNs = row => row.filter(x => x === 'N').length;` should suffice.

Answer (score -1):

The total count for the column-occurrence of a given value from a table needs to follow an approach similar to transposing a table into a matrix.

An generic implementation based on two nested [`reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) tasks then might look like the next provided code ...

```js
// function transpose(result, row) {
//   return row.reduce((matrix, value, idx) => {
// 
//     (matrix[idx] ??= []).push(value);
//     return matrix;
// 
//   }, result);
// }

function aggregateColumnValueCount(collector, row) {
  // return row.reduce(({ value, counts = {} }, currentValue, idx) => {
  return row.reduce(({ value, counts = [] }, currentValue, currentColumn) => {

    // const currentColumn = `column_${ idx + 1 }`;
    const currentCount = (counts[currentColumn] ??= 0);

    if (currentValue === value) {
      counts[currentColumn] = currentCount + 1;
    }
    return { value, counts };

  }, collector);
}

const table = [
  ['N', 'N', 'Y', 'N'],
  ['1', 'N', '2', 'N'],
  ['N', '1', '4', 'N'],
  ['2', 'N', 'N', '1'],
];
console.log(
  "column counts for value 'N' ...",
  table
    .reduce(aggregateColumnValueCount, {

      value: 'N',
      counts: [],
      // counts: {},

    }).counts
);
console.log(
  // table.reduce(aggregateColumnValueCount, { value: '2', counts: {} })
  table.reduce(aggregateColumnValueCount, { value: '2', counts: [] })
);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { min-height: 100%!important; top: 0; }
```